# How to use new wx.panel or wx.ListBox when press button event

Tags: python, csv, wxpython

I am new for python and try to create a app to process the data from different CSV file. My app always to process the first open CSV file data and I have no idea for where is wrong in my code? below is my sample:

Sample1.csv :

ABC,DEF,GHI

1,3,7

2,5,8

3,6,9

Sample2.csv :

JKL,MNO,PQR,STU

1,3,7,10

2,5,8,11

3,6,9,12

My app will open the CSV file and put the header of CSV file which like ABC,DEF,GHI into the wx.Listbox selection and process something if you click on the selection. It looks OK to open sample1.csv first but when I open the sample2.csv and click the JKL,MNO,PRQ and STU then the panel will go back sample1.csv data!
I don't know why? is need to clear the old panel then create a new? if yes How to  do? Or I need to create a new frame to process the csv data?

Thanks for your help !

```
import csv
import wx 

class Mywin(wx.Frame): 

def __init__(self, parent, title): 

    super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (550,500)) 

    toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
    OpenCsvBtn = wx.Button(toolbar, -1," Open CSV")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, OpenCsvBtn)

    self.Centre() 
    self.Show(True)          

def onListBox(self, event): 
    self.text.AppendText( "Current selection:"+event.GetEventObject().GetStringSelection()+"\n")

def OnClick(self, event):

    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    print("open the csv file and get the path")
    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'win.py')
    openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(frame, "Open CSV file", "", "", 
                                  "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv", 
                                   wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
    openFileDialog.ShowModal()
    csvPath=openFileDialog.GetPath()
    print(csvPath)
    with open(csvPath) as csvFile:
         csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)  

         i=csvReader.next()
         rest = [row for row in csvReader]
    print (i)

    box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
    self.text = wx.TextCtrl(panel,size =(200,400), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE) 
    languages = i #[title[0]]  
    lst = wx.ListBox(panel, size = (200,400), choices = languages, style = wx.LB_SINGLE)
    box.Add(lst,0,wx.EXPAND) 
    box.Add(self.text, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    panel.SetSizer(box) 
    panel.Fit() 

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.onListBox, lst) 

ex = wx.App() 
Mywin(None,'ListBox Demo')
ex.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fathom how you get the posted code to work. It certainly doesn't display the toolbar.
Due to the fact that you create the panel each time, it should work without you needing to do anything more but you should not declare `frame` as that was already created.
Below, is a hacked version of what I think you are attempting.
**Note that this code works with python 2.7, it will not work with python 3 as the API for toolbar has changed**

```
import csv
import wx

class Mywin(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (550,500))
        toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
        open_bmp = wx.Bitmap('3.bmp')
        tool1 = toolbar.AddTool(wx.ID_ANY, open_bmp, wx.NullBitmap)
        toolbar.Realize()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnClick, tool1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def onListBox(self, event):
        self.text.AppendText( "Current selection:"+event.GetEventObject().GetStringSelection()+"\n")

    def OnClick(self, event):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        print("open the csv file and get the path")
        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(panel, "Open CSV file", "", "",
                                      "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv",
                                       wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        openFileDialog.ShowModal()
        csvPath=openFileDialog.GetPath()
        print(csvPath)
        with open(csvPath) as csvFile:
             csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)

             i=csvReader.next()
             rest = [row for row in csvReader]
        print (i)

        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(panel,size =(200,400), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        languages = i #[title[0]]
        lst = wx.ListBox(panel, size = (200,400), choices = languages, style = wx.LB_SINGLE)
        box.Add(lst,0,wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(self.text, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(box)
        panel.Fit()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.onListBox, lst)

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Destroy()

ex = wx.App()
Mywin(None,'ListBox Demo')
ex.MainLoop()
```